# Rendering visually perfect squares in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

In OpenGL's fixed pipeline, by default, specifying vertex coordinates using `glVertex3f` is equivalent to specifying a location between -1.0 and +1.0 in screen space. Therefore, given a set of 4 perfectly adjacent screen-space vertices using `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` (or even `GL_QUADS`), and unless your window is already perfectly square, you will always render a rectangle instead of a perfect square...

Knowing the width, height and aspect ratio of a window, is there some way to correct this?
I have tried multiplying the vertex coordinates by the aspect ratio, which unfortunately seemed to achieve the same visual effect.

---

Here's the full source code I'm currently using:

```
#include "main.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "glut32.lib")


int g_width = 800;
int g_height = 600;
int g_aspectRatio = double(g_width) / double(g_height);
bool g_bInitialized = false;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(g_width, g_height);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Test App");
    glutDisplayFunc(onRender);
    glutReshapeFunc(onSize);
    glutIdleFunc(onRender);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}

void onInit()
{
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
}

void onRender()
{
    if(!g_bInitialized)
        onInit();

    static float angle = 0.0f;

    const float p = 0.5f * g_aspectRatio;
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(
        0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f
    );

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glScalef(1, -1, 1); // Flip the Y-axis
    glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    {
        glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);  // Red
        glVertex3f(-p, -p, 0.0);        // Top-Left
        glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);  // Green
        glVertex3f(p, -p, 0.0);         // Top-Right
        glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);  // Blue
        glVertex3f(-p, p, 0.0);         // Bottom-Left
        glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);  // Yellow
        glVertex3f(p, p, 0.0);          // Bottom-Left
    }
    glEnd();

    angle += 0.6f;
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void onSize(int w, int h)
{
    g_width = max(w, 1);
    g_height = max(h, 1);
    g_aspectRatio = double(g_width) / double(g_height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gluPerspective(45, g_aspectRatio, 1, 1000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
}
```

**EDIT**:
This has been solved... In the above code, I had defined `g_aspectRatio` as an `int` instead of a floating-point value. Therefore, it's value was always 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my (old) experience, that's just why you have an aspect ratio argument to `gluPerspective()`.

[The manual page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/gluPerspective/) says:

> In  general,  the aspect ratio in gluPerspective should match
>          the aspect ratio of the associated viewport. For example, aspect =  2.0
>          means  the  viewer's angle of view is twice as wide in x as it is in y.
>          If the viewport is twice as wide as it is tall, it displays  the  image
>          without distortion.

Check your `g_aspectRatio` value.

Comment: I've updated my question. Please refer to the source code I've added.
AFAIK, I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary...

Comment: OOPS! Found the bug.... `g_aspectRatio` was accidentally defined as an `int`... Thanks! It works now.

Answer (score -1):

> by default, specifying vertex coordinates using glVertex3f is equivalent to specifying a location between -1.0 and +1.0 in screen space

Wrong. Coordinates passed to OpenGL through glVertex or a glVertexPointer vertex array are in model space. The transformation to screen space happens by transforming into view space by the *modelview* matrix and from view space to clip space by the *projection* matrix. Then clipping is applied and the perspective divide applied to reach *normalized coordinate space*.

Hence the value range for glVertex can be whatever you like it to be. By applying the right projection matrix you get your view space to be in [-aspect; aspect]×[-1, 1] if you like that.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-aspect, aspect, -1, 1, -1, 1);
```